# Error en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

estoy aprendiendo sobre los procedimientos almacenados en oracle SQL Developer, quiero que me salga en columnas el resultado del procedimiento, columna dni, columna nombre, el resultado que obtengo ahora mismo es en linea, como se observa en la imagen que he adjuntado

Las BBDD son estas con sus valores para ir probando y aprendiendo sobre los procedimientos almacenados

```
 create table sucursales_pruebas_JJ( 
 codigo number(4),
 ciudad varchar2(30) not null,
 primary key(codigo)
 ); 

 insert into sucursales_pruebas_JJ values(1,'Cordoba');
 insert into sucursales_pruebas_JJ values(2,'Villa Maria');
 insert into sucursales_pruebas_JJ values(3,'Carlos Paz');
 insert into sucursales_pruebas_JJ values(4,'Cruz del Eje');

 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('22222222','Ana Acosta','Avellaneda 111','Secretaria',500,1);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('23333333','Carlos Caseros','Colon 222','Sistemas',800,1);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('24444444','Diana Dominguez','Dinamarca 333','Secretaria',550,2);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('25555555','Fabiola Fuentes','Francia 444','Sistemas',750,2);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('26666666','Gabriela Gonzalez','Guemes 555','Secretaria',580,3);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('27777777','Juan Juarez','Jujuy 777','Secretaria',500,4);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('28888888','Luis Lopez','Lules 888','Sistemas',780,4);
 insert into empleados_pruebas_JJ values('29999999','Maria Morales','Marina 999','Contaduria',670,4);


 create table empleados_pruebas_JJ( 
 documento char(8) not null,
 nombre varchar2(30) not null,
 domicilio varchar2(30),
 seccion varchar2(20),
 sueldo number(6,2),
 codigosucursal number(4),
 primary key(documento),
 constraint FK_empleados_sucursal
 foreign key (codigosucursal)
 references sucursales_pruebas_JJ(codigo)
  );
```

En el procedimiento almacenado le estoy pasando el parámetro de entrada que es la seccion por la que quiero filtrar la consulta, entonces hice un bucle porque con la consulta a secas me daba un error, se esperaban más resultados o algo así era, pero ahora quiero que me aparezca el resultado en columnas como si se tratará de un select normal

```
PROCEDURE SP_AUMENTO_SUELDO_SECCION(p_seccion VARCHAR2)
is
v_dni VARCHAR2(40);
v_nombre VARCHAR2(40);
v_sueldo NUMBER;
v_domicilio VARCHAR2(40);
v_ciudad VARCHAR2(40);
begin
  for datos in(
   SELECT empleados.documento, empleados.nombre, empleados.sueldo,empleados.domicilio, sucursal.ciudad
   into v_dni, v_nombre, v_sueldo, v_domicilio, v_ciudad 
    FROM empleados_pruebas_JJ empleados 
    right join sucursales_pruebas_jj sucursal 
    on empleados.codigosucursal=sucursal.codigo
    where empleados.seccion=p_seccion 
    )
    loop 
    v_dni:=datos.documento;
    v_nombre:=datos.nombre;
    v_sueldo:=datos.sueldo;
    v_domicilio:=datos.domicilio;
    v_ciudad:=datos.ciudad;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_dni);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_nombre);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sueldo);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_domicilio);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ciudad);
end loop;
end;
```

Imagen del resultado del procedimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado desea sería así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero mira los parametros que estas retornando, debes retornar un resultSet  
    PROCEDURE SP_AUMENTO_SUELDO_SECCION(p_seccion VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    AS resultSet SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
      OPEN resultSet FOR 
        (SELECT e.documento, 
               e.nombre, 
               e.sueldo,
               e.domicilio,  
               s.ciudad
          FROM empleados_pruebas_JJ e 
    RIGHT JOIN sucursales_pruebas_jj s 
            ON e.codigosucursal = s.codigo
         WHERE e.seccion=p_seccion)
     return resultSet
    end;

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` hace un salto de línea luego de imprimir la variable que le estás pasando. ¿Por qué no simplemente concatenar los resultados (con `||`) para mostrar por cada línea todos los datos de un mismo registro? De todos modos, insisto en que deberías utilizar un cursor... ¿Era solamente imprimir un registro por línea realmente tu idea? ¿O es que acaso querías retornar los registros como tal?

Comment: puedes detallarme un poco mas tu respuesta JackNavaRow

Answer (score 0):

En el cursor el into, sobra.
Prueba con esto

```
PROCEDURE SP_AUMENTO_SUELDO_SECCION(p_seccion VARCHAR2)
is
v_dni VARCHAR2(40);
v_nombre VARCHAR2(40);
v_sueldo NUMBER;
v_domicilio VARCHAR2(40);
v_ciudad VARCHAR2(40);
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DNI'||'#'||'NOMBRE'||'#'||'SUELDO'||'#'||'DOMICILIO'||'#'||'CIUDAD');
  for datos in(
   SELECT empleados.documento, empleados.nombre, empleados.sueldo,empleados.domicilio, sucursal.ciudad
    FROM empleados_pruebas_JJ empleados 
    right join sucursales_pruebas_jj sucursal 
    on empleados.codigosucursal=sucursal.codigo
    where empleados.seccion=p_seccion 
    )
    loop 
    v_dni:=datos.documento;
    v_nombre:=datos.nombre;
    v_sueldo:=datos.sueldo;
    v_domicilio:=datos.domicilio;
    v_ciudad:=datos.ciudad;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_dni||'#'||v_nombre||'#'||v_sueldo||'#'||v_domicilio||'#'||v_ciudad);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Esperemos que te responda (lo que proponés fue lo mismo que le sugerí).